# Some sub-folders are in detached HEAD state

Tags: git, bitbucket

I really do not understand what happens here.
I want to do git clone on my server and I receive this output:

```
error: cache entry has null sha1: js/plugins/jspdf/libs/Blob.js
fatal: unable to write new index file
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
```

Now in my editor (netbeans) next to the folder name I see [00000000...] and on mouse over it's written: "Not on a branch (detached HEAD state)".

In bitbucket I see: "Blob.js → 000000000000 [000000000000]"

Please some one can help me to solve this situation?
THANKS

Comment: Something has gone seriously wrong but it's not clear what.  What OS are you using, and are you doing something that's a bad idea like trying to work directly within a network-shared directory ("folder"), e.g., Dropbox?

Comment: No I'm not working with shared folder. The error (0000...) is on my windows 8.1 64bit (working with netbeans) and I can see it on bitbucket as well. What you recommend to do in order to fix it? something like to set up a new repo or something?

Comment: I don't know what's gone wrong locally, and you don't say where your repo is on bitbucket (if it's public at all), so I can't say any more.